# react hook form doesn't detect value of textbox if value exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to fill textbox with data from database, setting values to state and then using value of each textfield to show information in text field and if want to modify I add inchange to change, the problem is when a submit the form using react hook form(useFormContext), react hook form doesn't detect the field has value so when i submit form textfield are empty and the validation validations are triggered

**My state:**

```
const [PersonData, setPersonData] = useState({
    id:undefined,
    name:undefined,
    surname:undefined,
    nss:undefined,
    phone:undefined
  })

const {
    register,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useFormContext({});
```

**Get information from db:**

```
 axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url:`xxx`,
      data: data,
      config: { headers: {
          'Accept': 'text/plain',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' 
        }}
      })
        .then((data) => {
          const DataR = data.data;
            if (data.status === 200) {
               setPersonData(DataR);
                 }
             })
```

**My textfield:**

```
  <FormControl sx={{ width: '41ch' }} >
          {errors.nombrePaciente && <Alert severity="error">Este campo es requerido</Alert>}
          <label htmlFor="Nombres">Nombres</label>
                  <TextField 
                      id="personName" 
                      name="name"
                      variant="outlined"
                      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                      value={PersonData.name}
                      
                      {...register("personName", {
                        required: true,
                        value:  PersonData.name,
                        onChange: (e) => setPersonData({name: e.target.value})} )}
                       
                      />
```

`